# Changing our contact email address in Event Templates

Tags: civievent, message-templates

When I create a new event template, which has an email address other than that used in other events we have, changing the email automatically also changes the email address in the other existing events.

We run several events but the contact people can be different. How can I create a new event template without this changing the email address in existing events?

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Best wishes,
Minna
Baffled in Liverpool

Answer (score 1):

I assume the email address you are referring to is on the location tab.  If so, the assumption is a location has a fixed email address.  When you change the email address on a location it changes it everywhere that location is used.

So you need to create a new location.  Unfortunately, location appears to only look at the address part so if you create a new location with the same address as another but a different email or phone number, it doesn't create a new address.  It just updates the existing address.

The work around is to make the address part different.  I'd suggest using the Supplemental Address 1 to indicate who the coordinator is.   You could simply put their name there or something like Event Coordinator: Name or Attn: Name.

Comment: Many thanks Paul! I will see how that works.